# Visual Studio Git Remote list still shows deleted branches

Tags: git, visual-studio, azure-pipelines, visual-studio-2022

Is the some button I can hit to make Visual Studio understand that a delete remote branch is no longer there?

The scenario is this: I have an Azure DevOps git branch that I have pushed to the main server and worked on from several different machines.  Eventually, (after merging to master) I delete it, both locally remotely using the Visual Studio interface in the dropdown window.

Just to be sure the remote delete worked, I go to the Asure web interface for repos and check.  The branch is clearly gone; My delete has worked.

But when I then go to a different machine where I once worked on the branch and look at my list of remote branches, the deleted branch still shows up.  Even if I do a fetch and look again it is still there.  Even if I delete my local copy.  It seems Visual studio doesn't get the memo that the remote branch is gone.

So in order to clean up my list of remote branches on the second machine, I must either delete it remotely... again.  Or I can make a clean cone of the repo, then it's gone too.

Is there some other button/menu command I can issue to fix this?

Comment: No idea how to do it properly in VS, but in base Git, just run `git fetch --prune` or `git remote prune origin`, or set `fetch.prune` to `true`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Even if I delete my local copy. It seems Visual studio doesn't get the memo that the remote branch is gone.

Just to be clear, what you're talking about here is not VS, but git. And git intentionally doesn't lose remote branch tips when you fetch, the action you want is called "prune".

To access pruning from VS, use this setting:

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  I knew it must have been something like that.  I feel foolish for not having gone through all the GIT configuration options in visual studio before asking my dumb question...

Comment: It's okay, neither have I. I actually typed that you can't do it from VS (since it's not on any of the buttons visible on the IDE), and was about to tell you how to do it on the command line, when I decided to look at the settings page just to make sure lol. I've never used pruning in my life, more branch names don't bother me and it won't save space either (the commits are still there, you need a `gc` to get rid of those).

Comment: @Joe Don;t feel foolish - first thing I did was head to stackoverflow to see if anyone had figured it out..